# When you click on a button contained in a file inside a container, it jumps to a specific frame in the as3 project

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a swf file named ff2.swf that contains a but1 button inside it. I call it inside a container in the FLV project, and when I export the project, the file appears inside the container. That's fine.
But when I click on the but button, I want to move to frame number 5 in the project, and this did not happen.
I used the following code, but it shows the file in the container, but the button does not work when I click on it. I hope you can help me solve the problem.

```
stop();
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:String = "ff.swf";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
 loader.load(request);

 var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
 container.addChild(loader);
 addChild(container);

 //The problem is in the following code

 but1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openNewScene);

 function openNewScene(event:MouseEvent):void {
   gotoAndStop(5);   
}
```